# How to find the local extrema of this function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

$f(x,y) = 3x^3 + y^2 + z^2 + 6xy - 2z +1$

Solution

$Fx = 9x^2 + 6y
\\
      Fy = 2y + 6x
\\
      Fz = 2z - 2$

Solving gave me

(x,y,z) = (0,0,1)

(x,y,z) = (2,6,1)

```
  Fxx = 18x

  Fyy=2y

  Fzz=2

  Fxy=6    

  Fzy=0

  Fzx=0
```

Now in order to find 'D', I found the determinant of the Hessian matrix and got that D = -936, therefore I concluded it is a saddle point for (2,6,1). Could someone please tell me if this approach is correct and if the answer is right?  Thank you.

Comment: $F_{xy}=6,$ not $0.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for the correction, however the determinant of the Hessian matrix still gives me a negative value with Fxy = 6, therefore it is still a saddle point? Other than this mistake, is my approach correct you think?

Comment: the critical point is $(2,-6,1)$?

Comment: And (3rd mistake, found by Sameer Abbas) $F_{yy}=2,$ not $2y.$

Comment: Perfect, thank you guys! I made too many mistakes than I thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x,y,z) = 3 x^{3} + 6 x y + y^{2} + z^{2} - 2 z + 1$. Then
$$\nabla f =  \left[\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f{\left(x,y,z \right)}\\\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f{\left(x,y,z \right)}\\\frac{\partial}{\partial z} f{\left(x,y,z \right)}\end{matrix}\right] =\left[\begin{matrix}9 x^{2} + 6 y\\6 x + 2 y\\2 z - 2\end{matrix}\right] = 0 \\
\implies (x,y,z) = (0,0,1)  \lor (x,y,z) = (2,-6,1)$$
Also we have:
$$\textbf{H}_f = \left[\begin{matrix}18 x & 6 & 0\\6 & 2 & 0\\0 & 0 & 2\end{matrix}\right] \implies \left| \textbf{H}_f\right| = 72 \left(x - 1\right)$$
So $|\textbf{H}_f| = -72$ at $(0,0,1)$ which is a saddle point and $|\textbf{H}_f| = 72$ at $(2,-6,1)$ which is a local minimum.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I get that 72 is just the determinant but how did you get (x-1) though?

Comment: I did cofactor expansion along the last row. The only term you get is: $2[18x \times 2 - 6^2] = 72x - 72 = 72(x-1)$

Comment: Got it! Thank you. I didnt know one could calculate the determinant from the bottom row instead of the top row

Comment: No prob :). By the way, you can calculate the determinant of a matrix by doing cofactor expansion along any row or any column, not just the first and last row.